Why is pnpm with node-linker to pnp and symlink false still generating a node_modules folder?
I've got a monorepo setup. I've set the following options in my .npmrc file at the root of my project:
node-linker=pnp
symlink=false

However, when I run my inital pnpm i I still get node_modules folders with everything at the root of the project and into all my packages. What might I be missing?

What does pnpm config get node-linker and pnpm config get symlink return?

@John pnpm config get node-linker returns pnp and pnpm config get symlink returns false

I just ran pnpm i again after removing all the node_modules folders. Now i still have a node_modules at the root with everything in the .pnpm folder inside that. However, my packages each have only a .bin file in their node_modules folders. Is that expected, or is there still something off?
